# Library to open ZVI files

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

Does anyone know if there exists a .NET library to open ZVI files. I know that there exists a lot of ZVI reader but I couldn't find a ZVI reader or a library for C# or .NET. Every help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if it's going to help you but you can open  .ZVI with ImageJ, there is even a macro code in here http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Loci-plugin-and-macro-file-conversion-Questions-td5003928.html how to convert them automatically to tifff.